# Display LWC component as a full width and height page but not via VFP

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components, aura

Is there any way we can display LWC  as a separated page similar to VisualForce page? I know we can create an app than aura component which holds LWC component on VFP but we don't want to use VFP at all. We can open LWC component in a tab with full width but the top header - salesforce navigation is there. I know we can overwrite css to not display salesforce top header but this I would find as a not good practice. So the question is is there any other way to display LWC as a full width and height page without VFP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Lightning App](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_aura_application.htm). Like a VFP, they are addressable via a URL:

```
https://mydomain.lightning.force.com/my_ns/appName.app
```

Which you write as:

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <c:myLwc />
</aura:application>
```

You can also just add the [lightning__AppPage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_configuration_tags) target and and make a full page app if you prefer, though it would then have some minor padding on all sides, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your response, how to actually preview it somewhere or add it to app exchange to check if it works? https://my-domain.lightning.force.com/lightning/myAppName.app doesnt work at all

Comment: @panatoni You need to create the app (you can use Developer Console for this). Also, I should mention you can run a Local Lightning Server if you're using SFDX: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/get_started_local_dev_setup.html

Comment: I did it but it still display salesforce navigation on top as you can see on the screen the component which is black header has a full width but it's still "inside" the salesforce https://imgur.com/a/A67579R

Comment: @panatoni If you use a Lightning App, it will be completely self-contained. https://imgur.com/a/0YaASbY

Comment: what is my_ns in the url ? I added and deployed an app using aura:application but once I'm putting it in similar way in the url it simply says page doesnt exist.

Comment: @panatoni `c` if you don't have a namespace. Also, if you just click Preview App in the developer console, it should open the right URL for you.

Comment: I got my app added https://imgur.com/a/K1yQuo7 even added to app launcher but once I go to my app is still shwoing with the sfdc navigation : /

Comment: @panatoni No, not a Lightning App Builder app, a Lightning App. You don't add them to anything, you navigate to them directly.

Comment: https://domain.lightning.force.com/c/APPNAME.app - works well! Thanks a lot!